# Is there a way to change RecyclerView item position in layout

Tags: android, list, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to move RecyclerView items at the top of the layout, starting from a certain index of the list, but I don't know if this is even possible.

Example Image of what I am trying to do:

[image]

I already tried to find solution on the internet but I did not find anything.

Comment: Can you please make it more clear what you want to achieve? The image attached shows two columns. Do you want to have your recycler view to have two columns side by side?

Comment: You want to use `GridLayoutManager` for your `RecyclerView`.